# Using axios for posting images to cloudfa

Tags: javascript, api, axios, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload an image to Cloudfare with the write API. Currently I'm using axios, because I was unable to achieve this with plain javascript.
My code consists in:

```
export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const response = await axios.get(
    "https://www.datocms-assets.com/45562/test-image.png",
    { responseType: "stream" }
  );

  const form = new FormData();
  form.append("image", response.data, "test.png");

  try {
    const postRes = await axios.post(
      `https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/my-id/images/v1`,
      form,
      {
        headers: {
          ...form.getHeaders(),
          Authorization: `Bearer my-api-key`,
        },
      }
    );
    console.info("response", postRes);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error while uploading to cloudflare", error);
  }
};
```

I'm getting this error (sorry for the length):

```
request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    ...(more logs)...
    _header: 'POST /client/v4/accounts/my-key(I removed it, but I'm using it)/images/v1 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------930843423466862063114860\r\n' +
      'Authorization: Bearer my-key\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/0.26.1\r\n' +
      'Host: api.cloudflare.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      'Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    ...(more logs)...
  response: {
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    headers: {
      date: 'Wed, 30 Mar 2022 00:30:01 GMT',
      'content-type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      connection: 'close',
      'cf-ray': '6f3cbbe73c67d2d4-EZE',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache',
      'set-cookie': [Array],
      vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
      'cf-cache-status': 'DYNAMIC',
      'cf-images': 'err=5400',
      'expect-ct': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      server: 'cloudflare'
    },
    config: {
      transitional: [Object],
      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [Object],
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/my-id/images/v1',
      data: [FormData]
    },
```

Can anyone help me please? I'm losing my here with this haha. Thanks!

Comment: According to your [previous question's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71668654/283366) `curl` example, the field name should be `file` but you are using `image`. Other than that, everything else looks fine

Comment: FYI, Axios error objects are easier to read if you use `error.toJSON()`

Comment: @Phil thanks for all your answers! I really appreciate it

Comment: Hi @Phil, do you know why I'm getting this error with svg images? 'ERROR 9422: Decode error: image failed to be decoded: Uploaded image must have image/jpeg or image/png content type\n', I'm running the code I show in this question with the corrections you made me. It works fine with png and jpg, but breaks with svg. Thanks

Comment: Does the error message not speak for itself?